docker run error for google chrome and selenium. session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
This is my docker file section to download chrome and chromedriver and I'm using xvfb to record the screen in a virtual display.
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor -o 
/usr/share/keyrings/google-linux-signing-key.gpg \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/google-linux-signing- 
key.gpg] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && apt-get clean

RUN wget -q -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for- 
testing-public/126.0.6478.126/… \
    && unzip -o /tmp/chromedriver.zip -d 
/tmp/ >> /build_logs/chromedriver_install.log \
    && ls -la 
/tmp/chromedriver-linux64 \
    && mv /tmp/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver 
/usr/bin/chromedriver \
    && chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver \
    && rm /tmp/chromedriver.zip

Selenium code section:
driver = None
try:
    # Configure Chrome options for headless mode
    chrome_options = Options()
    # chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") # Ensure 
    headless mode is enabled
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080") # Set 
     window size
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu") # Disable GPU 
    acceleration
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")

    # Specify the path to your ChromeDriver
    # driver_path = 'D:/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe'
    # Ensure the correct path to chromedriver
    chrome_service = Service(executable_path=driver_path)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, 
    options=chrome_options)
    # Navigate to the webpage
    driver.get(url)

    # Allow time for the page to load and for recording to 
    # capture
    time.sleep(10) # Adjust as needed
    print(driver.title)
 finally:
    stop_screen_recording(ffmpeg_process)
    # Quit the browser
    # if "driver" in locals():
    if driver:
       driver.quit()

url = 'https://pythonbasics.org'

# ffmpeg docker path:
ffmpeg_path =  "/usr/bin/ffmpeg"

# docker driver path:
driver_path = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"

# to run from docker
output_file = "test.mp4"
print('starting the script...')
record_webpage(url=url, output_file=output_file, 
ffmpeg_path=ffmpeg_path, driver_path=driver_path)

I'm getting errors during docker run. Error: selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally. (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) Stacktrace:............
What can I improve in the dockerfile or the selenium crawl code?

I added chrome option:
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
and it worked.

For me now it is sometimes running, and sometimes it crashes. So it is at least an improvement. Thank you for the answer.
